# Setup a Contact Form 7 with GMap at side

Tags: php, google-maps, wordpress, contact-form

I'm building a site where I use Contact Form 7 for contact page. Also I use a plugin called **Comprehensive Google Map Plugin** so I generated the map shortcode using this one. I want to put the form and the Google Map side by side. This is the [site](http://www.espiralinfinitoca.com/). Any recommendation on this? Any other plugin that give me the same behavior?

Cheers and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that easily by editing your CSS.
Go to your dashboard and click Editor under Appearance Tab on the left side.

Now press `Ctrl+F` and type `#post`.
You can see the below code there:

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
/* Posts & Pages
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#post {
    float: left;
    width: 650px;
}
```

Remove the line `width: 650px;` from there.

After that press Update File button.

Thats it. Now check your contact page.

Cheers!!!